# Change Work Item State labels in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO) and our choices for State on Backlog Items are

- Approved
- Committed
- Done
- New
- Removed

Unfortunately Approved and Committed are a little ambiguous in our workflow so I'd like to change the label associated with it.  Perhaps from Comitted to "In Progress"

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the listed state name with VSTS for now but you can add more states for the "State" list and hide the old one.

Refer to following steps to add a custom state:

1. Open your account from Web Portal.(Do not open team project)
2. Click "Account settings" button to open control panel.
3. Navigate to "Process" tab.
4. Create an inherited process for the Process Template you use.
5. Click the created inherited process to open it.
6. Click "Work Item Types" tab.
7. Click the work item type you want to update and then click "States".
8. Click "New State" button to add a new state.
9. Go back to "Process" home tab.
10. Select the updated process and choose "Change team projects to use XXXXX" to change your project to use the new process.

Now, you will see the custom state when you create the work item.

Refer to "Modify the state workflow on existing work item types" section in this link for details: [VSTS Process Customization futures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/vsts-process-customization-futures-january-2016/).